# What is the difference between the Yocto and Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, linux, operating-systems

Recently I come to about the IIoT solution of siemens which have Yocto Linux    https://www.14core.com/siemens-simatic-iot2000-iot2020-iot2040-arduino-ide-integration/. As I am already working on raspberry pi and raspberry pi based Revolution Pi known as RevPi which uses raspbian based OS .here you will find the use full information about the RevPi https://revolution.kunbus.com.

I don't have much knowledge about these Linux based open-source Operating System. Can anyone help me to understand in what aspect Yocto Linux is different from Raspbian OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a good whitepaper [here](https://www.prevas.dk/download/18.58aaa49815ce6321a327da/1506087244328/Yocto_Debian_Whitepaper.pdf) which describes in detail the differences between Yocto and Debian(Raspbian is a flavor of Debian).

From the whitepaper, the gist is:

> Debian is good for fast trials, proof of concept and desktop like
>   environments on hardware already supported by Debian with large
>   memories and limited requirements for maintenance, traceability and
>   reuse across different hardware targets.

and

> Yocto is good for customized embedded environments with various
>   hardware support and small to large memories and requirements for
>   maintenance, traceability, longevity and reuse across difference
>   hardware targets.

Comment: This is not a good comparison. The whitepaper you posted did not mention raspbian at all. While Raspbian OS is a flavor of Debian, it is optimized for the Raspberry Pi hardware. Yocto essentially does the same thing (customize/optimize) but using Poky as reference